# The LINQ expression could not be translated although ToLists is used

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following code, where I first create a list object `assessmentItems`, and then use it inside a LINQ to get the `CurrentScore`.

```
List<AssessmentItem> assessmentItems =
    _context.AssessmentItems
            .Include(ai => ai.Assessment).ThenInclude(assess => assess.Evaluator)
            .Where(ai => ai.IsActive &&
                         ai.Assessment.PeerReviewAssignmentId == peerReviewAssignmentId &&
                         ai.Assessment.RubricId == rubricId).ToList();


List<RubricDTO> resultToReturn = _context.Rubrics
                .Include(r => r.RubricItemCategories)
                .Where(r => r.Id == rubricId)
                .Select(r => new RubricDTO
                {
                    Ranking = r.Ranking,                       
                    Description = r.Description,
                    RubricItemCategories = r.RubricItemCategories.Select(ric => new RubricItemCategoryDTO
                    {
                        Id = ric.Id,
                        Description = ric.Description,
                        RubricItems = ric.RubricItems.Select(ri => new RubricItemDTO
                        {
                            Id = ri.Id,
                            Title = ri.Title,                     
                          
                            CurrentScore = assessmentItems.Count > 0 ? assessmentItems
                                                  .Where(aitem2 => aitem2.RubricItemId == ri.Id && aitem2.Assessment.EvaluatorId == userId)
                                                  //.Take(1)
                                                  .Select(s => s.CurrentScore)
                                                  .FirstOrDefault() : 0,

                        })
                    }).OrderBy(ric => ric.Order).ToList()
                }).ToList();
```

However, I receive the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'aitem2' could
> not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be
> translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a
> call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or
> 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for
> more information.

Any ideas why this might be happenning?

Comment: Rather *because* `ToList` is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me hep you to simplify your query. Includes are not needed because you have custom projection. If you add `ToList` for subquery elements - it will be not translatable. If you need translatable query - work with IQueryable.

```cs
var assessmentItems = _context.AssessmentItems
    .Where(ai => ai.IsActive &&
                    ai.Assessment.PeerReviewAssignmentId == peerReviewAssignmentId &&
                    ai.Assessment.RubricId == rubricId);

var resultToReturn = _context.Rubrics
    .Where(r => r.Id == rubricId)
    .Select(r => new RubricDTO
    {
        Ranking = r.Ranking,                       
        Description = r.Description,
        RubricItemCategories = r.RubricItemCategories.Select(ric => new RubricItemCategoryDTO
        {
            Id = ric.Id,
            Description = ric.Description,
            RubricItems = ric.RubricItems.Select(ri => new RubricItemDTO
            {
                Id = ri.Id,
                Title = ri.Title,                     
                
                CurrentScore = assessmentItems
                                    .Where(aitem2 => aitem2.RubricItemId == ri.Id && aitem2.Assessment.EvaluatorId == userId)
                                    .Select(s => s.CurrentScore)
                                    .FirstOrDefault(),

            })
        }).OrderBy(ric => ric.Order).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```